# Openpyxl - find hidden rows in ReadOnlyWorksheet

Tags: python-3.5, openpyxl

I have a problem with detecting which rows are hidden when I open workbook in read-only mode.

It works flawlessly when I set `read_only` parameter to `False` while loading workbook, because then I can iterate over `row_dimensions` to check which rows are hidden - but opening workbook in read-write mode takes much longer (~2 mins vs ~20 secs in read-only mode) and consumes over 1GB of RAM.

Unfortunately read-only worksheets don't have `row_dimensions` attribute.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: `column_dimensions` and `row_dimensions` make no sense in `read-only`mode. You could probably derive your own parser for this based on the `ReadOnlyWorksheet`.

Comment: @CharlieClark: thank you for your answer. Could you please elaborate why `column_dimensions` and `row_dimensions` make no sense when sheet is opened in `read-only` mode?

Comment: Because it's data only access and `row_dimensions` also requires parsing the whole worksheet.

Answer (score 2):

The underlying issue is that the parser is used once and discarded after iterating over all the rows. This is how read_only mode can optimize memory allocation and generate rows upon request. Interestingly enough, the parser itself is still creating the `row_dimensions` with the row attributes in it!

There are a couple of work arounds you could attempt. In lieu of forking and creating an official fix that exposes the ReadOnlyWorksheet parser, I went with monkey patching:

```
from openpyxl.worksheet._read_only import ReadOnlyWorksheet, WorkSheetParser, EMPTY_CELL

# The override:
class MyReadOnlyWorksheet(ReadOnlyWorksheet):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.parser = None

    def row_is_hidden(self, row_index):
        str_row_index = str(row_index)
        if self.parser and str_row_index in self.parser.row_dimensions:
            return self.parser.row_dimensions[str_row_index].get('hidden') == '1'
        if self.parser is None or row_index > self.parser.row_counter:
            raise RuntimeError('Must generate the row before calling')
        return False

    def _cells_by_row(self, min_col, min_row, max_col, max_row, values_only=False):
        """
        The source worksheet file may have columns or rows missing.
        Missing cells will be created.

        Logically the same but saves the parser to "self" during row iteration

        """
        filler = EMPTY_CELL
        if values_only:
            filler = None

        max_col = max_col or self.max_column
        max_row = max_row or self.max_row
        empty_row = []
        if max_col is not None:
            empty_row = (filler,) * (max_col + 1 - min_col)

        counter = min_row
        idx = 1
        src = self._get_source()
        parser = WorkSheetParser(src, self._shared_strings,
                                 data_only=self.parent.data_only, epoch=self.parent.epoch,
                                 date_formats=self.parent._date_formats)
        ### Cache parser in order to check generated row attrs ###
        self.parser = parser
        for idx, row in parser.parse():
            if max_row is not None and idx > max_row:
                break

            # some rows are missing
            for _ in range(counter, idx):
                counter += 1
                yield empty_row

            # return cells from a row
            if counter <= idx:
                row = self._get_row(row, min_col, max_col, values_only)
                counter += 1
                yield row

        if max_row is not None and max_row < idx:
            for _ in range(counter, max_row+1):
                yield empty_row

        src.close()

# the monkey patch:
import openpyxl.reader.excel
openpyxl.reader.excel.ReadOnlyWorksheet = MyReadOnlyWorksheet

# the test drive:
from openpyxl import load_workbook
file_location = ''  # load your file
workbook = load_workbook(file_location, data_only=True, keep_links=False, read_only=True)

for worksheet in workbook.worksheets:
    row_gen = worksheet.rows
    for i, row in enumerate(row_gen, start=1):
        if worksheet.row_is_hidden(i):
            continue  # do not process hidden rows.
```

This does what you need, but beware! I would add sufficient test coverage before using in production (think things like future version re-keying row_dimension dict, removing row_dimensions from read_only parsing, etc). You can similarly add your own accessors to the worksheet that exposes other row attrs (or return the entire dict).

Happy coding!